# Querying Chinese addresses in Googlemap API geocoding

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, cjk

I'm following the demo code from article of phpsqlgeocode.html

In the db, I inserted some Chinese addresses, which are utf-8 encoded. I
found after urlencode the Chinese address, the output of the address
would be wrong.  Like this one:

http://maps.google.com.tw/maps/geo?output=csv&key=ABQIAAAAfG3KxFZXjEslq8VNxMBpKRR08snBovzCxLQZ9DWwpnzxH-ROPxSAS9Q36m-6OOy0qlwTL6Ht9qp87w&q=%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F132%3F

Then it outputs 200,5,59.3266963,18.2733433 (I can't query this through PHP, but through the browser instead).

This address is actually located in Taichung, Taiwan, but it turns out to be
in Sweden, Europe. But when I paste the Chinese address(such as 台中市西屯區智惠
街131巷56號58號60號) in the url, the result turns out to be fine!

How do I make sure it sends out the original Chinese
address? How do I avoid `urlencode()`? I found that removing `urlencode()` doesn't change anything.

(I've change the MAPS_HOST from maps.google.com to
maps.google.com.tw.)
(I'm sure my key is right, and other English address geocoding are
fine.)

Comment: Should have php tag.

The url encoding is clearly not working. %3F in the url is a '?', which is the result of a failed encoding or decoding.

It appears that urlencode doesn't support UTF-8, according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: urlencode just encodes PHP's native byte strings, in whichever encoding they happen to be; it knows nothing about Unicode. Something has mangled the Chinese characters already before urlencode got a look in.

Answer (score 0):

```
q=%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F132%3F
```

decodes to:

```
?????????132?
```

so something has corrupted the string already before URL-encoding. This could happen if you try to convert the Chinese characters into an encoding that doesn't support Chinese characters, such as Latin-1.

You need to ensure that you're using UTF-8 consistently through your application. In particular you will need to ensure the tables in the database are stored using a UTF-8 character set; in MySQL terms, a UTF-8 collation. The default collation for MySQL otherwise is Latin-1. You'll also want to ensure your connection to the database uses UTF-8 by calling 1mysql_set_charset('utf-8')`.

(I am guessing from your question that you're using PHP.)